# Excel VBA - If Then Replace

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, replace

I am very new to VBA and I have read so much on the If-Then-Replace that I think I'm confusing myself.  Within my worksheet I have two columns that come in with more data than what I need and I have to get it pared down in order to concatenate it.

Column H (Header) has the following data in each cell: Network: Series: Episode : Data

Column J (Header) has the following data in each cell: Network: Type: Type2: Type3

I run a text-to-columns to get it down to have the Network in 1 column and the Series in the 2nd column.

What I need is a Search in Column J for "specific network".  If this is true then replace the network in Column H.

**Question:  Will I need to also run a text-to-columns in Column J to get a 1:1 comparison?
Question: Can you help me with the VBA code to do the Find-If-Then-Replace?**

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do what you're looking to do... If it works for you, please mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left.

```
Sub Freplace()
dim i as int
dim s as string
i = 1
s = "specific network"

Do until Cells(i,10).Value = ""
If Cells(i,10).Value = s Then Cells(i,8).Value = s
i = i+1
Loop
End Sub
```